# Java: change an element in a prepopulated List of string array

Tags: java, string, list, arrays, set

I have a List of string array already populated in storeInv. How do i change a specific element in the string array? For example the code below...

Thanks =]

```
List <String[]> storeInv ;  //assume already populated with elements
String[] store = storeInv.get(5);
store[1] = 123;

store.set(5, store[1]);  //this gives me an error.
```

Comment: And `store[1] = 123;` doesn't give you an error?

Comment: @battousai622: you mean something like *store[5] = store[1]* ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you mean `storeInv.set(5, store);`  But you don't need to, because it's already there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
List <String[]> storeInv = ...
String[] store = storeInv.get(5);

// This updates an element in one of the arrays.  (You cannot
// assign an integer literal to a String or a String array element.)
store[1] = "123";

// Compilation error!  'store' is an array, so there is no 'set' method.
store.set(5, store);

// This updates an array in the list ... but in this
// case it is redundant because the 5th list element
// is already the same object as 'store'.
storeInv.set(5, store);
```

Comment: the set method isn't working for me. I can't get it to show up in the autocomplete in Eclipse, and I try using it on a String[]. Huh?